# The method getSystemService(String) is undefined for the type new Thread(){}

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm attempting to multithread my code, and there are no errors apart from the one which reads in the title. I'm quite new to coding, so now that I have to supposedly turn my code inside out to allow the app to run smoothly, I'm unsure how to tackle the problem.

My Java code:

```
   package com.bipbapapps.leagueclickerapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainClass extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    public float goldCount;
    Button minionClick;
    Button storeClick;
    Button storeDismiss;
    TextView textGoldCount;
    ImageView spinningBars;
    String textTotal;
    private SharedPreferences prefs;
    PopupWindow pw;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set full-screen
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.mainlayout);

        // Initialize variables from popup window
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(inflater.inflate(R.layout.storemenu,
                null, false));
        storeDismiss = (Button) pw.getContentView().findViewById(
                R.id.menudismissid);

        prefs = getSharedPreferences("LeagueClicker", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        goldCount = prefs.getFloat("goldCount", 0.0f);

        // Linking the variables
        minionClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.minioncentreid);
        storeClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.storeimageid);
        textGoldCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textviewtop);
        spinningBars = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.spinningbarsid);
        // String which will display at the top of the app
        textTotal = goldCount + " Gold";

        // Setting TextView to the String
        textGoldCount.setText(textTotal);
        textGoldCount.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "mechanical.ttf");
        textGoldCount.setTypeface(tf);
        textGoldCount.setTextSize(35);

        // Setting onClickListeners
        minionClick.setOnClickListener(this);
        storeClick.setOnClickListener(this);
        storeDismiss.setOnClickListener(this);

    }



    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        prefs.edit().putFloat("goldCount", goldCount).commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        goldCount = prefs.getFloat("goldCount", 0.0f);
        t.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        prefs.edit().putFloat("goldCount", goldCount).commit();
        Log.d(prefs.getFloat("goldCount", 0.0f) + "derprolw", "ejwfjbrea");
    }

    public void barsAnimation() {
        Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                R.anim.spinningbarsanimation);
        rotation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        spinningBars.startAnimation(rotation);
    }

    Thread t = new Thread(){

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.minioncentreid:
                goldCount += 1.0;
                prefs.edit().putFloat("goldCount", goldCount).commit();
                textTotal = goldCount + " Gold";
                textGoldCount.setText(textTotal);
                textGoldCount.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                break;

            case R.id.storeimageid:
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                View popupview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.storemenu, null);
                final PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(popupview, 300, 450);
                pw.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

                storeDismiss = (Button) pw.getContentView().findViewById(
                        R.id.menudismissid);
                storeDismiss.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        pw.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                pw.showAsDropDown(storeClick, 0, 0);
                break;

            }

        };

    };

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

The thread is at "Thread t = new Thread(){". Does anyone know what I can do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

`this` is the context of the `Thread`, while you are actually looking to use `.getSystemService` of the Activity.

Use instead:
`MainClass.this.getSystemService`

Comment: You mean `MainClass.this.`

Comment: Nice, that cleared up that error :)
Although now Eclipse is telling me "The method onClick(View) from the type new Thread(){} is never used locally". What does this mean?

Comment: The section where you set the listeners (i.e. "// Setting onClickListeners") is referring to the click listener in the main class (which is empty). Did you mean to use the contents of the click listener inside the Thread?     P.S. please mark the answer as the correct.